# Use date as Views Contextual filters

Tags: 7, views

I need to retrieve all nodes where updated date is between date A and date B.
I had a look at contextual filters and they seem to allow only the equality operator (SELECT where date = X) whereas I need greater than and lower than operators (SELECT where date > X).

Any idea to achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No need adition module but date module.
go to your views add a `filter` with type `date` choose `Date: Date (node_revision)` pass `Configure extra settings for filter criterion Date: Date (node_revision)` with  your optionals ,and in `Configure filter criterion: Date: Date (node_revision)` select **Is between** option.
If you want expose your filter check  `Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it`

Comment: Don't forget to enable the 'date views' sub-module to get data filters available in views.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this sandbox project [views arguments in filter](http://drupal.org/sandbox/itangalo/1086472). It permit to use arguments in filter criteria and then all the operators of the filter criteria with the arguments of contextual filter.

You can read the post below wich discuss about this (possible) evolution of views
http://drupal.org/node/357082